# on activity change edittext and spinner values are gone

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-spinner

I'm trying to create a registration form. Where user enters his information and some spinner stuff that he can choose from. I added a button also so that user can add location from googlemapsv2. So when I click the button I open a new activity to show gmaps but when I go back to registration form all the dataare gone. How can I prevent this?

Comment: to close the new activity I opened to add location, I used finish(); after saving longitude and latitude which is all I need tho thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use savedInstanceState method in your form activity and retrive the data you previously saved.

Check out this link from the documentation :)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without source code we have to guess ...

Help the community to help you ;)